# How to specify the multicycle constraint for all paths using certain clock enable (in Vivado)?

Tags: constraints, vhdl, timing, vivado

I'm designing a huge system in a FPGA, operating at system clock 320 MHz.
Certain operations must be performed at slower clock - 160MHz due to long critical paths.
I can introduce a clock enable signal, lets call it CE2, used by registers surrounding such long operations.

According to the old Xilinx documentation: http://www.xilinx.com/itp/xilinx10/books/docs/timing_constraints_ug/timing_constraints_ug.pdf (page 60), I can add a special constraint:

```
NET CE2 TNM = slow_exception;
NET clk TNM = normal;
TIMESPEC TS01 = PERIOD normal 8 ns;
TIMESPEC TS02 = FROM slow_exception TO slow_exception TS01*2;
```

defining such multicycle timing constraint.
Unfortunately the above case is not descrbide in newer versions of the documentation,
and especially in documentation for Vivado tools.

Does anybody know how the above problem should be solved in XDC file for Vivado?

Comment: If this is a significant amount of logic it would be better to separate it into a 160 MHz domain assuming the domain crossings can be managed.

Comment: Unfortunately, number of domain crossings would be too high. I highly rely on the fact that 160MHz and 320MHz clocks are in phase. Maybe I could use PLL to keep reasonable phase relationship, but it seems too risky. Anyway if it could be done in ISE, I hope that it can be also done in Vivado...

Comment: What about UG903? It describes how to setup clocks, related clocks (Ch. 4) and how to specify multi-cycle constraints (Ch. 6).

Comment: The problem is how to automaticly create multicycle constraints for all signals connecting registers using certain clock enable. 
I have also asked this question on Xilinx forum, and received a very good answer: http://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Timing-Analysis/How-to-specify-the-multicycle-constraint-for-all-paths-using/td-p/553366

Comment: On the topic of just using a phase-related half speed clock (generated from an internal PLL), I've seen this done and it works very well. You can also just apply a generic data path only constraint between the two clock domains (use the tighter period) to avoid having to deal with numerous timing exceptions. Having the clock path untimed isn't quite as accurate, but we've never had an issue with it in the temp chamber and long term reliability tests while running a little faster than the speeds you mention.

Answer (score 0):

The new way of doing multicycle constraints in Vivado specifies the number of cycles rather than the direct period.

You can also use datapath_only constraints for false paths and clock crossings, which are more directly akin to what you used in ISE
This is a datapath_only constraint:

```
create_clock -period 8.000 -name arbitraryClkName -waveform {0.000  4.000} [get_ports portName];
set_max_delay -from [get_pins {hierarchical_location_source/CLK}] -to [get_clocks arbitraryClkName] -datapath_only 16.000;
```

Here is an actual multicycle hold command:

```
set_multicycle_path -hold 2 -from [get_pins {hierarchical_location_source/CLK}] -to [get_pins {hierarchical_location_sink/D}];
```

Here is the constraint documentation for Vivado 2014.3; you can find multicycle path documentation on page 79:
http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2014_3/ug903-vivado-using-constraints.pdf